# SET ANSI_NULLS ON Default

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to the forums and SQL Server so just trying to boost my rating and ask some simple questions.

I have a list of hundreds of stored procedures and on all of them they all say `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`

is there  a way to default this so that you do not have to declare it in the beginning of each script?

Comment: boosting your rating is not sufficient reason to ask a question

Comment: It's a genuine question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not literally stored within the stored procedure.

The setting is captured when a stored procedure is created, and when you ask SQL Server to script a stored procedure, it adds the appropriate setting above the `CREATE PROCEDURE` so that you can *recreate* the stored procedure accurately.

See [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx):

> The Database Engine saves the settings of both SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET ANSI_NULLS when a Transact-SQL procedure is created or modified. These original settings are used when the procedure is executed. Therefore, any client session settings for SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET ANSI_NULLS are ignored when the procedure is running.

And [`sys.sql_modules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx):

> **uses_ansi_nulls**  **bit**  Module was created with SET ANSI_NULLS ON.

Comment: No, it's captured in a separate column in `sys.sql_modules`. I've added some links to relevant documentation (and choice quotes).